# Getting sed: -e expression #1, char 41: unterminated `s' command

Tags: shell, sed

I am running shell script to update the pom version but getting the below error.

sed: -e expression #1, char 41: unterminated `s' command

Shell Script

```
#!/bin/sh            
tag=$(grep '<version>' $2 | sed 's/<version>[^-]*-\(.*\)<\/version>/\1/')
sed -i "s/<version>.*<\/version>/<version>$1-${tag}<\/version>/" $2
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>org.acumos.onboarding</groupId>
        <artifactId>onboarding-app</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-</version>
        <name>Onboarding app for public use</name>
        <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0-</version>
                <relativePath />
        </parent>
```

Here instead of 4.0.0, I am expecting 4.0.2

I am running the script as ./script.sh <version_name> pom.xml

New pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>org.acumos.onboarding</groupId>
        <artifactId>onboarding-app-open</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-</version>
        <name>Onboarding app for public use</name>
        <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0-</version>
                <relativePath />
        </parent>

</project>
```

My output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>org.acumos.onboarding</groupId>
        <artifactId>onboarding-app-open</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-</version>
        <name>Onboarding app for public use</name>
        <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0-</version>
                <relativePath />
    </parent>

</project>
```

Script run method ./script.sh 3.0 pom.xml

Comment: Could you please post samples of input and expected output too in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Use an XML-aware tool to edit XML.

Comment: Added the pom.xml file

Comment: @SvDhote, do you want to change all version tags values? Or any specific 
 tag ones?

Comment: Only the specific version i.e the first version line (<version>4.0.0-</version>)

Comment: @SvDhote : My guess is that either `$1` or `$tag` contain a slash or some other character, which causes `sed` to get out of step. I suggest that you run your code with `set -x` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk '
match($0,/.*<version>([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+-<\/version>/) && ++count==1{
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/\.0/,".2",val)
  print val
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/.*<version>([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+-<\/version>/) && ++count==1{  ##Using match function to match regex of <version> digits dot(1 or more occurrences) followed by digits - </version> and making sure its happening only 1 time.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)  ##Creating val which is sub string of matched regex above.
  sub(/\.0/,".2",val)            ##Substituting .0 with .2 in val to get exact version asked by OP.
  print val                      ##Printing val here.
  next                           ##next will skip all statements from here.
}
1                                ##1 will print edited/non-edited lines here.
' Input_file                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***NOTE:*** Above will print the results, once you are Happy with results shown on terminal then append  `> temp && mv temp Input_file` to above code to save output into Input_file itself.

---

---

To run this in bash script try following.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v ver="$1" '
match($0,/.*<version>([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+-<\/version>/) && ++count==1{
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/\.0/,".2",val)
  print val
  next
}
1
' "$2"
```

Now run it as follows(don't forget to give execute permissions to script).

```
./script.bash "3.0" "your_file"
```

Comment: can you please share the usage as in how to run it, I have added the script like this


awk '
match($0,/.*<version>([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+-<\/version>/) && ++count==1{
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/\.0/,".2",val)
  print val
  next
}

Not added the last 1 and Input_file

Comment: @SvDhote, if I am getting it right `$2` is your passed file name right? If this is the case in your shell script after `#!/bin/bash` post my program and in my program in place of `Input_file`(I had written) write `"$2"` there, then try it out once? Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @SvDhote, Simply run my program ON your file first to check you are getting correct output or not, once you are sure output is correct then follow instructions given by me in my previous comments, let me know how it goes.

Comment: It is not running gone to the waiting state, below is the file let me know if something wrong here.
#!/bin/sh
awk '
match($0,/.*<version>([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+-<\/version>/) && ++count==1{
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/\.0/,".2",val)
  print val
  next
}
1
'
"$2"
And yes $2 I am giving for accepting input file from user

Comment: @SvDhote, No, have one liner in this form `awk 'match($0,/.*<version>([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+-<\/version>/) && ++count==1{val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/\.0/,".2",val);print val;next} 1' "$2"` once and try again, it will only print it on screen once you get right output we will look into save it into same file then, let me know.

Comment: It is printing on the screen but not giving desire output, I am running it as follow
./script.sh 4.0.2 pom.xml. Added the command in one liner. Instead of 4.0.2 it is giving the actual value only i.e 4.0.0

Comment: @SvDhote, oh ok version you are also passing to your script, then try following: `awk -v ver="$1" 'match($0,/.*<version>([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+-<\/version>/) && ++count==1{val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/\.0/,ver,val);print val;next} 1' "$2"` and let me know then?

Comment: It is still not giving the desire output 
Running as ./script.sh 3.0.0 pom.xml, so instead of 4.0.0 which is present in file not updating to 3.0.0 on the screen print.
Script
#!/bin/sh

awk -v ver="$1" 'match($0,/.*<version>([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+-<\/version>/) && ++count==1{val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/\.0/,ver,val);print val;next} 1' "$2"

Comment: @SvDhote, See this: `./script.ksh 3.0.0 file10
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0         <version>43.0.0.0-</version>`
 its working fine for me, when I test this in a script(I have cut short the output as its not coming in comments).

Comment: can you please share your script (awk script), might be something missing from my end

Comment: @SvDhote, please check my answer I have added how to run code in script form now, let me know where you are stuck.

Comment: Not sure why it is not working in my case, I have followed as explain by you above.
Adding my pom.xml file and output in the question section

Comment: @SvDhote, could you please do run command `cat -v file` on your file(where file is your name of file) run it and see if you see control M characters in it and let me know?(control M characters could affect working of codes by the way).

Comment: No not getting that control M char 
cat -v pom1.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>org.acumos.onboarding</groupId>
        <artifactId>onboarding-app-open</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-</version>
        <name>Onboarding app for public use</name>
        <parent>

Comment: @SvDhote, OK, could you please run my 1st command shown on directly on file like: `awk -v ver="3.0.0" 'match($0,/.*<version>([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+-<\/version>/) && ++count==1{val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/\.0/,ver,val);print val;next} 1' YOUR_FILE` once and let me know what it does, don't run this on script run this on terminal once and let me know then.

Comment: Still not being able to update the output when run directly from terminal
awk -v ver="3.0.0" 'match($0,/.*<version>([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+-<\/version>/) && ++count==1{val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/\.0/,ver,val);print val;next} 1' pom1.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

Comment: @SvDhote, it wouldn't save output into input file(as mentioned above), is it printing correct values?

Comment: No, It is still showing the same value on terminal only

Comment: @SvDhote, its really working fine for me :) I tried everything to help here, not sure why its not working for you. Is your actual file is same as shown samples?

Comment: No, actually it's really huge file so didn't put the complete file. Anyways no issue, really appreciate your time and effort @RavinderSingh13. Will try to figure and check more on this, will surely let you know, if any finding.

Comment: @SvDhote, sure, this should work I am still not able to believe this is not working :)